# Reading from a database partition

Tags: postgresql, go

I have the following code snippet that creates and writes to a Postgres Partition:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-pg/pg/v10"
    "github.com/go-pg/pg/v10/orm"
)

type Log struct {
    tableName struct{} `pg:"logs,partition_by:RANGE(log_time)"`

    Id        int       `pg:"id,pk"`
    LogString string    `pg:"log_string"`
    LogTime   time.Time `pg:"log_time,pk"`
}

func main() {
    db := pg.Connect(&pg.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:5432",
        User:     "postgres",
        Password: "postgres",
        Database: "db_name",
    })
    defer db.Close()

    /*
        The code below generates the following MySQL query

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "logs" (
            "id" bigserial,
            "log_string" text,
            "log_time" timestamptz,
            PRIMARY KEY ("id", "log_time")
        ) PARTITION BY RANGE(log_time)
    */
    err := db.Model(&Log{}).CreateTable(&orm.CreateTableOptions{
        IfNotExists: true,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    logStartTime := time.Date(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    logEndTime := logStartTime.AddDate(0, 0, 3)
    for logStartTime.Unix() <= logEndTime.Unix() {
        logData := &Log{
            LogString: fmt.Sprintf("Log at %s", logStartTime.String()),
            LogTime:   logStartTime,
        }

        // before insert: always try to create partition
        err = createNewPartition(db, logStartTime)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        _, err = db.Model(logData).Insert()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        logStartTime = logStartTime.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
    }
}

// createNewPartition will create new partition of logs table if not exist.
// Partition created by in one month range start from first date of the month to last date of the month.
func createNewPartition(db *pg.DB, currentTime time.Time) error {
    firstOfMonth := time.Date(currentTime.Year(), currentTime.Month(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    firstOfNextMonth := firstOfMonth.AddDate(0, 1, 0)

    year := firstOfMonth.Format("2006")
    month := firstOfMonth.Format("01")
    sql := fmt.Sprintf(
        `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs_y%s_m%s PARTITION OF logs FOR VALUES FROM ('%s') TO ('%s');`,
        year, month,
        firstOfMonth.Format(time.RFC3339Nano),
        firstOfNextMonth.Format(time.RFC3339Nano),
    )

    log.Println("Creating partition ", sql)

    _, err := db.Exec(sql)
    return err
}

func readFromPartition(db *pg.DB) error {
    return nil
}
```

However, I want to to implement the method `readFromPartition`... what would look like? Can I read from each partition? Given a data log, I want to query in the right partition.

Answer (score 1):

To read from the correct partition, you'll need to determine which partition the data resides in based on the LogTime. Then, you can construct a query that specifies the appropriate partition using the pg.Query and pg.Model functions. Here's an implementation of the readFromPartition function that retrieves log entries based on a given logTime:

```
func readFromPartition(db *pg.DB, logTime time.Time) ([]Log, error) {
    firstOfMonth := time.Date(logTime.Year(), logTime.Month(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    year := firstOfMonth.Format("2006")
    month := firstOfMonth.Format("01")

    partitionName := fmt.Sprintf("logs_y%s_m%s", year, month)

    var logs []Log
    err := db.Model(&logs).TableExpr(partitionName).Where("log_time >= ? AND log_time < ?", logTime, logTime.Add(24*time.Hour)).Select()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return logs, nil
}
```

Here's how to use the readFromPartition function to read logs:

```
func main() {
    // ... (existing code)

    logStartTime := time.Date(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    logEndTime := logStartTime.AddDate(0, 0, 3)
    for logStartTime.Unix() <= logEndTime.Unix() {
        // ... (existing code)
        logStartTime = logStartTime.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
    }

    // Read logs for a specific date
    logs, err := readFromPartition(db, time.Date(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, logData := range logs {
        fmt.Println(logData.LogString, logData.LogTime)
    }
}
```

This code will read logs from the partition that corresponds to the specified logTime. If there are any logs in the partition for the given date, it will print them.